# ROS Answers SE migration: RGB colour

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all-

I know pcl::PointClouds carry color data packed as a float and it can be subscribe using sensor msg in ros.
but What happens when this is saved in a binary .pcd file, and then converted to ascii?
Any chance that the color data is still valid if I later read that ascii number in as a float?

Is there currently any good way to save the r, g, b, color info as separate values?

Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11596/rgb-colour/) by [youga](https://answers.ros.org/users/1191/youga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2011-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reading the ASCII is as a float is almost certainly going to Do Something Completely Terrible; it would need to read it in bitwise-identical, and (unless you're printing to a great many significant figures, and can accurately predict how your parsing routine is going to work), this is unlikely to happen.

As for .pcd files, have you tried it? Run the experiment...

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1